# SQL Error SELECT statement returns entire table

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, encryption

The problem is that this "SELECT" query yields the wrong result from my database.

I've already tried hard coding values to obtain the result I want, aswell as altering the SQL command slightly, to make I less complex

```
GetScoutDataSQL="SELECT firstname,secondname,age,gender,ethnicity,address,postcode,medicalinfo FROM scoutinfo WHERE parentID=(SELECT parentID FROM usercredentials WHERE username=%s)"
mycursor.execute(GetScoutDataSQL,(EntrUser.get(),))
myresults=mycursor.fetchall()
print(myresults)
```

The expected result is one row being returned:

```
Kreem, Krumble, 16, Male, Chinese, Yerst, BT66453, gAAAAABcMIeqEkHS3FjRE_pr3tBHh551GncHKmV6sPpLyjdkePKAaRdoOyuFDK4eFqmZcOHoU8OcoL1e5_L1906Y14OMDiiI_Wo80jrm3M2LKhs7UHYGyWs=
```

The actual result is all data in the scoutinfo table being returned.

Comment: You can start with using `fetchone()` if you expect 1 row and why do you have that second comma after `EntrUser.get()`? I think the line must be: `mycursor.execute(GetScoutDataSQL, EntrUser.get())`. And if EntrUser.get() is not a string, you have to cast it first.

Comment: ('Poppy', 'Harlow', '12', 'Female', 'Chinese', 'Bangor', 'BTT3454', 'Allergy:\nPeanuts\nMilk'), in other words, the first row of the scoutinfo table.

Comment: Even after the changes I mentioned above?

Comment: Yeah it seems to be ignoring the sub query, the comma must be their as the data for mycursor.execute has to be inputted as a tuple. EntrUser.get() does have a string in it.